# Using Jar file in Python

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have to use a stemmer available on github in my Python code. The author of that github project has given a Usage command line in the README which is:

```
  java -jar khoja-stemmer-command-line.jar test-in.txt test-out.txt
```

Each of the row of a dataframe in python has to go as test-in.txt to this command and test-out.txt will give the output. 
Can anyone please how can I integrate this from beginning (command line in python) to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import os
os.system("java -jar khoja-stemmer-command-line.jar test-in.txt test-out.txt")
```

If you are using a version of Python above 3.5, you can use `subprocess` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)).

Comment: Worth noting, depending on what you need to do it might be better to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: Ok one other question: I have a Java class let's suppose **Stemmer**. If I had to access this in the Main java file it would have been like:

`Stemmer mystemmer = new Stemmer (); 
String result = mystemmer.stem(token);
`

However, I have that 'token' present in python, and I have to pass it like that^ to the java class method and then get the result in python. can you please tell how to do that?

Comment: That should be a new question :)